# changing image during flip css animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I currently have a rotating image that flips around and has writing on the back using animated css, however what I want is that when the image flips around it changes with another image so it has a solid colour instead of a reversed version of the image.

*CSS*

```
.hover-img {
position: relative;
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
background:url(bbclike/topright.png);
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    line-height:200px;
text-align:center;
font-size:0;

}
.hover-img:hover{
-webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);
font-size:14px;
color:white;
background-color:#FF0;

}
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="hover-img">
Text Goes Here
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://codepen.io/jjhesk/pen/lHdCA/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put in hover section whatever you want when user hovers the div... E.g. :

```
.hover-img:hover{
background:url(---HERE IMAGE 2---);
font-size:14px;
color:white;
background-color:#FF0;
}
```

Working fiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jap48/)

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try this out

http://jsbin.com/tejiduq/1/edit?html,css,output

change the container class, so that you can manipulate DOM class.

```
//html 
<div>
    <i class="icon"></i>
</div>
<br>
<input class="button" type="button" value="flip">

//css
div{
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

div .icon {
    background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_chrome.gif") no-repeat;
}

div.ie .icon{
  background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_edge.gif") no-repeat;
  transform: scaleX(-1)
}

//javascript 
$(".button").click(function() {
  $("div").toggleClass("ie");
});
```

Hope this will find you useful.